Do you say "I can't sleep" for repeated event and "I can't fall asleep" for one specific occasion?
When you say "I like tea", you mean I always like tea because that is my habit or repeated event.
But, when you say "I would like some tea", you mean I want to drink some tea at this specific situation only. For example, you are at a party and in front of you are many kinds of drinks and you say to the server "I would like some tea". You just want some tea now only at this specific moment you always like it.
Similarly, when you say "I can't sleep", does it mean that is your habit as it happens repeatedly for a long period of time?
Also, when you say "I can't fall asleep", does it mean right now at this moment you can not drift off but that is not your habit that happens for a long time?
Note: Someone says "I can't sleep" might refer to the whole process of sleeping. Say, I sleep for a while, then a noise wakes me up, then I sleep for a short time before being woken up by another noise. In this case, I have broken sleep but I still can sleep a little bit.
"I can't fall asleep" means I am unable to get into the sleeping state. That implies I have no sleep at all.

I can't sleep and I can't fall asleep don't have the distinction the OP described,  habitual against one-off.
The former doesn't have the habitual sense; to have that meaning, we need some context:
I can't sleep after having a coffee.
The same elaboration can also make the fall asleep version habitual:
I can't fall asleep after having a coffee.
In both cases, we can also say
I won't be able to sleep (or 'fall asleep') after having a coffee.
Edit
I have trouble sleeping and I can't sleep also can have the habitual sense in the right context, for example, in a discussion about the state of tiredness of the speaker.

If I wanted to make a bare statement about regularly not sleeping, I would be more likely to say something like I have trouble sleeping.

Something like "Why are you always so tired?" "I can't sleep." seems fine to me, and in context has a habitual sense.

Thanks, @Peter Kirkpatrick and Stuart F.  I've edited my answer.
